# Postgres cross tabs mixes categories in result set

Tags: sql, relational-database, crosstab, postgresql-9.5

I have a query returning me three columns 'Date', 'District' and 'Total'. There are four districts but some time a district may not have record for corresponding date. I want to put all my districts in column and their total in rows as ..

Date, District1, District2, District3, District4

While in my rows will be date along with the total value per district.

I am using crosstab to get the desired results. But in the result total for one district is listed in other district though the datewise grand total is same.

I don't know why crosstab query mixes categories. Please help.

Comment: please elaborate with data and code samples

Comment: I have a table with three columns,' survey_date, district, total'. There are four districts and the table lists the date wise total for each district. Now I want to move my districts to columns and display respective total in row using  'SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT
survey_date,
district,
total
FROM
sample') AS ct(survey_date varchar, khuzdar NUMERIC ,loralai NUMERIC,zhob NUMERIC);' The query runs and returns the results but total for one district is listed under other district. I hope now my problem is quite clear for you. thanks.